# Cassandra multi datacenter setup

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster on `datacenter1` with 3 nodes and three pvt IP addresses and another `datacenter2` with 3 nodes and 3 pvt IP addresses for inter node communication.

In order for the nodes to communicate with each other among the two datacenters to form a 
ring, how would the communication between these nodes take place with pvt address, as Private
IPadress communication is not there between two different geographically located datacentres.

What should be the approach here?

Comment: Do you mean to say that there is no communication link between the two data centres ??

Comment: Two data  centres can communicate over public IP .But internode communication between nodes in each datacentre is public. How to make them communicate across datacentres

Answer (score 0):

You don't state this explicitly, but it sounds like there are also public IP addresses on the nodes, is that the case?

The two data centers need to be able to communicate with each other somehow. If they can't do it via the private IP, then use the public IP, which presumably is internet facing. Enable encryption for the internode communication.

Set the rpc_address to the private IP and connect your Cassandra clients to that interface, or strictly use the public IP for all communication.

If on the other hand, there is not also a public IP that you can use to connect the two data centers, then you will have to find some other way to establish communication between the nodes. The IPs used in for the listen_address values in all data centers need to be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: communication of nodes in datacentres to be done with public IPS is the right approach .I wanted to know  that